# SQL datatype BIT assign values

Tags: sql, types, datatable

Can Bit be assigned values?

for example instead of 
0=False, 1= true

it will be like below
0=outdoor 1=indoor

if able to then how do i assign the values to bit?

(SQL code)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Bit is a product specific data type.)

Answer (score 0):

No, Bit is a single bit, it has 3 (in MS SQL) possible states: 1,0 and NULL

The standard way to do this would be to have an 'Indoor' field, and use 1/0 as true/false.

In TSQL You could use a case statement to present this as indoor/outdoor at the database level:

```
select 
    case when indoor=1 then 'indoor' 
    else 'outdoor' end
        as location 
    from table_name
```